# how to avoid duplicates or cartezian product in final join gpm1eff_total

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this query:

```
WITH gpm1eff_total AS
(
       SELECT customer_global_account_id,
              Round((price_net_total - average_effective_purchase_price_net_total) / NULLIF(price_net_total,0),2) AS gpm1eff_total
       FROM   biz__customer_global_account_order_history_full bcgaoh )
SELECT DISTINCT Md5(Lower(ca.primary_email_address)) AS email_md5,
                ca.customer_global_account_id,
                bcgaoh.gpm1eff_total
FROM            biz__customer_account AS ca
 LEFT JOIN            gpm1eff_total         AS bcgaoh
ON              ca.customer_global_account_id = bcgaoh.customer_global_account_id )
```

The query before the join with gpm1eff_total is maintaining the desired amount of rows: aprox 10 mil. After the join it results in 60 millions. I tried a lot of conditions and filters and other things but I cannot find a solution.  It would help a lot if you can provide a solution for this issue.

Comment: Presumably there are multiple records with the same value for customer_global_account_id.

Comment: That is why I used the distinct in the select

Comment: But if you have multiple records in the CTE for the same account but with different gpm1eff_total values then the distinct is not going to get you back to one record per account. This seems to be a data issue, not a code issue, so you need to look at your data and work out why you have more records than you expected - it’s not really something anyone can help you with as we don’t have access to your data

Comment: select count(*) from biz__customer_account
1 000 000
select count(*) from biz__customer_global_account_order_history_full
1 500 000
When looking at this, is it normal to generate 6 000 000 records? I mean, even if the metrics are multiple for one account, you should not see so many because you are just bringing a metric from second table if exists, right?

Comment: This is just maths, you get what you get when you multiple the matching records in each table. But it’s either right or wrong, depending on what you want to achieve - and if it’s wrong then it doesn’t matter if there is 1 extra record or 100 million extra records, it’s still wrong. Assuming you only want 1 record per account then you need to sort out your CTE logic so that’s what it returns